# How to load src from server to xtype: image

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a xtype `image` like

```
 items: [
{
    xtype: 'image',
    name: 'img',
    src: '#',
    flex: 1
}]
```

And i load data from server (PHP) like

```
Mypanel.down('form').getForm().load({ 
...
});
```

and server like

```
$temp['img'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,"http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-avatar-64x64.png");
$results['success'] = true;
$results['data'] = $temp;
print json_encode($results);
```

Everything working except for `xtype='image'` that's not working.

How to load src from server to `xtype: image` thanks

Comment: Image doesn't mixin `Ext.form.field.Field`, so it's not recognized as a field. You'll need to manually call `setSrc` on it.

Comment: Why aren't you posting that as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Evan has already mentioned in the comment. You can set `image` src when form is loaded, i.e. on on form event [`actioncomplete`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-event-actioncomplete).

This is how I do in my code :

```
actioncomplete: function(form, action) {
    // get image component by querying it and set src
    this.queryById('user-image').setSrc(action.result.data.userImage);
}
```